# how to pass any class name in ArrayAdapter

Tags: java

I have a Food class in this class i have number of arrays with class name and i am trying to pass this class name to ArrayAdapter

```java
package foodapp.example.com.foodapp;

public class FoodCategories extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView listfoods = getListView();
        ArrayAdapter<Food> listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<Food>(FoodCategories.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Food.Foods);
        listfoods.setAdapter(listadapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: please answer to this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to pass the class name as string the you need a single line of code like `FoodCategories.class.getName()`

Your code:

```
public class FoodCategories extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ListView listfoods = getListView();
    ArrayAdapter<Food> listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(FoodCategories.class.getName(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,);
    listfoods.setAdapter(listadapter);
  }
}
```

Comment: i have one more class that name is Food i just passing this name to ArrayAdaper in Foodcategories class